# Pagination in Java, how to paginate a List of objects

Tags: java, pagination

I'm studying java, and I'm trying to paginate a list of objects, is it possible using only java?

```
public class Produto {
    public static List<Produto> estoque = new ArrayList<>();
    private String nome;
    private Double preco;
    private int quantidade;
```

I'm using this toString()

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nProduto: " + nome + ", preco: R$"
            + preco + ", quantidade: " + quantidade;
}
```

I got this pagination to work:

```
public static <Produto> List<Produto> getPageProduct(List<Produto> produtos, int page, int pageSize) {
    if(pageSize <= 0 || page <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid page size: " + pageSize);
    }

    int fromIndex = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    if(produtos == null || produtos.size() <= fromIndex){
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    return produtos.subList(fromIndex, Math.min(fromIndex + pageSize, produtos.size()));
}
```

But I cant get around having to input manually the number of the page

```
System.out.println(getPageProduct(getProducts(), 1, 5));
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

What would be the best solution?

Comment: Best solution for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the number of pages based on the size of the `List` and the page size.

```
final int pageSize = 5;
final int pages = (getProducts().size() + pageSize - 1) / pageSize;
for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
    System.out.println(getPageProduct(getProducts(), i, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll just fix the pageSize to 5.